# Java - check space between string

Tags: java, string, swing, space

I developed a compare text tool using Java Swing. My comparison login works like this.

```
String A = "Hello World  Java"
String B = "Hello World Java"
```

What i did is, I basically `split` the string use `" "(space)` then add into my array list. The arraylist will look like this.

```
array1(0) = {Hello} array1(1)={World} array1(2)={Java}
array2(0) = {Hello} array2(1)={World} array2(2)={Java}
```

Then I compare using the first element in array1 with first element in array2. If it equals the compare is **PASS** and if it fails I need to show as **FAIL**. And the out put will be like this.

```
<pass>Hello<pass><pass>World<pass><pass>Java<pass>
```

I have an enhancement where I need to show the spacing as well. So my final output need to be like this.

```
<pass>Hello<pass><quote><pass>World<pass><quote><quote><pass>Java<pass>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: When you invoke split method by `" "` you should get extra spaces as "" strings in your array.

for example `"hello hello  hello    helleo".split(" ").length` returns 8

Comment: @ОлександрСамсонов I don't think so. in you case it only returns 4 not 8.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586656/extract-all-occurrences-of-pattern-k-and-check-if-string-matches-k-in-1-pass) may helpful

Comment: i tryed that. and i got result 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace parts of original string with elements from array, where elements would be "enhanced" with information of pass or fail.

```
void checkString(String orig, String part, Boolean passed) {
    if (passed) {
        a.replace(part, "<pass>" + part + "<pass>");
    } else {
        a.replace(part, "<fail>" + part + "<fail>");
    }
}
```

So your example:

```
String A = "Hello World  Java"
String B = "Hello World Java"

// Do comparison, like you do

// take your first array
array1(0) = {Hello} array1(1)={World} array1(2)={Java}

// call method for each part in array
checkString(A, array1(0), isPassed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run some simulation of this, and i have this results:

```
String A = "Hello World  Java"
```

output:

[Hello, World, , Java]

```
String B = "Hello World Java"
```

output:

[Hello, World, Java]

so, to solve this, i use the replace to clean the final output, like:

```
Arrays.toString(yourString.split(" ")).replace(" ", "").replace(",,", ",")
```

I think it will work with every input.

Hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
public static String compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
    String op = "";
    int len = a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String aVal = "";
        String bVal = "";
        if (a.length > i) {
            aVal = a[i];
        }
        if (b.length > i) {
            bVal = b[i];
        }
        if (aVal.equals(bVal)) {
            op += "<pass>" + a[i] + "<pass>";
        } else {
            op += "<fail>" + a[i] + "<fail>";
        }
        if (i != len - 1) {
            op += "<quote>";
        }
    }
    return op;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String A = "Hello World Java1 A";
    String B = "Hello World Java";
    String[] splitA = A.split(" ");
    String[] splitB = B.split(" ");
    System.out.println(compare(splitA, splitB));
}
```

Output:

```
<pass>Hello<pass><quote><pass>World<pass><quote><fail>Java1<fail><quote><fail>A<fail>
```